# How to get my facebook bot to see what the user has "Liked" using his profile?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-chat

This is my first question at stackoverflow, so kindly excuse me if I am not following a standard format.

I have created a facebook bot using different APIs (IMDB, Goodreads, CNN etc.) using Node.js, but the conversations with the users are very precise. I was hoping if there is any way I can use my bot to see what the user has "liked" using his profile so that my bot can talk about those subjects to keep the conversation going.

Has anyone of you implemented anything like this? Kindly share your thoughts and procedure how I can achieve this.

Also, I will highly appreciate if you guys can share some ideas which I can implement in my bot.

Thanks in advance,

Sid

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the (Page) likes of the user, you need to authorize the user with the `user_likes` permission. Without authorization, this is all you get: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It really helps